# Get modelform to output custom name for modelform fields

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have a modelform:

```
class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):
    emailVerified = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate', 'id': 'emailVerified'}))
    domainNm = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate', 'id': 'domainNm'}))
```

In versions of django before 2+ I was able to just create `verbose_name=something` to change the *display* value of a modelform's field name different from what the model's field name actually is.

For example, on my form it displays:
`domainNm` and `emailVerified`

How can I get it to display:
`Domain Name` 
`Verifying Email`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verbose_name` is an an attribute of model fields, not form fields. For forms you use [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#label). Neither of these have changed in Django 2.